# unicode-math and oldstyle figures

Tags: luatex, fontspec, unicode-math, oldstylenums

I'm trying to find a good way to archive the following using `fontspec`, `unicode-math` and `lualatex`:

1. almost global oldstyle figures including inline math
2. lining numbers for displayed equations, e.g. `equation`.

My current unstable, ugly solution is the following.  I say unstable because class options like `fleqn` will break it to the ugliness. . . well take a look:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Tex Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont[]{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}
%% PROBLEM   : No +onum in this font (or Cambria Math)
%% "SOLUTION": Take numbers from normal font
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{Tex Gyre Pagella}
%% PROBLEM   : Not old style figures in display env.
%% "SOLUTION": Reload the Math variant since it ain't got onum.
\everydisplay={\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num}]{Tex Gyre Pagella Math}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\centering
123\textit{x}\textsubscript{456}\\
$123x_{456}$
\begin{equation}
123x_{456}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output is something like this:

[image: Output with different number styles in display and inline]

Spending quite a bit of time going through the manuals of `fontspec`, `unicode-math` and `mathspec` I have not been able to find a better solution.  The `version` argument to `setmathfont` (of `unicode-math`) seems to expect stuff like `bold`.

Bonus question: am I breaking some typographic style?

Comment: What's the sense of having different figures in inline and display math?

Comment: My numbers inline are easy to interpret, e.g. magnitudes and references.  In text I prefer old style figures (osf).  In displayed equations I may want to avoid pitfalls of  osf.  Is it good style and advisable?  I don't know.  Testing with some smaller documents suggests it works OK (IMO).  Edit: Do let me know if this breaks some typographic practices.

Comment: I don’t really think using old style figures in math is a good idea. A quick search gives http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29100/using-old-style-numerals-in-xelatex-in-math-mode#comment57071_29100, it and the next comments are interesting to read.

Comment: I don't know if my answer will suit you but I'll try my best. Two days ago, I answered a *very* similar question regarding archaic fonts. You can find the post here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352447/how-to-write-like-old-mathematical-papers/356414#356414). I hope that my post will be helpful to you. Cheers.

Comment: Does `\usepackage{etoolbox}` then `\AtBeginEnvironment{equation}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Monospaced,Lining}}}` work?