# 1920s maths textbook font

Tags: fonts

I was wondering if the font used in this old mathematics textbook (which I've seen in so many other books as well) is available on LaTeX, and if it covers maths as well. Thanks.

PS I've looked at [this](http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/hartke/hartke.pdf) survey of fonts but no matches as far as I can tell.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the users of TeX.SE. If you do a search on the site TeX.SE. and I do not remember badly that there are several answers just on how to get a font style similar to what you are looking for. It's probably a typographic style not supported by the TeX distribution. In 1920 there was no TeX and they are probably characters of a publishing house.

Comment: A larger choice is shown in [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: You can see the similar (or same) old question clicking this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352447/how-to-write-like-old-mathematical-papers The fonts are similar but they are not the same.

Comment: The text font looks like [Monotype Modern](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/monotype-modern/), i.e. the font DEK used  to design TeX's default font [Computer Modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Modern). However, the greeks, integral and summation sign in CM are quite different. I don't know a suitable replacement for that.

Comment: Thank you all for you kind replies. @Sebastiano in particular, the font mentioned in the answer you linked looks similar, and equally pleasant to read.

Comment: @lilasteroid I am happy when I help to others. My since regards.